# Slow emulation when using self-built WinCE6 image

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong: Using Microsoft's Device Emulator 3.0 with one of the included WM6.5 runs fine and feels quite responsive, even when debugging own (.net-)applications.

But if I try an own custom image, the user interface inside the emulator is extremely unresponsive and sometimes it takes two seconds for WinCE to register a simple click on a UI button.

There are no informative kernel debug prints...

Details:

- Platform Builder for WinCE6R2
- ARMV5 Emulation target
- Industrial control template with minimal options
- Release build
- Emulator options: 128MB RAM, NE2000 emulation, 480x272x16 video settings

Is there anything I can take a look at to further troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to debug just applications you can build an image using the Virtual PC BSP. It provides better performances than the ARM emulator. You can connect using TCP/IP and even copy data files by mounting the VHD file in your machine if you have a Windows 7/8 PC.

Comment: Interesting workaround. Does this work for CE6? Can I deploy and debug applications on VirtualPC using VS2008?

Comment: Yes, IIRC there is a Virtual PC BSP also for CE 6. And you can use VS2008 to develop apps for CE 6 too.

Comment: I ended up in using the latest version of Microsoft's Device Emulator. Version 3 seems to run way better than version 1 did.